# IronPython: how can I run init code when I import a module using clr.AddReference()?

Tags: ironpython

I was wondering if there was a way that you could get init code to run upon importing a .NET assembly using clr.AddReference(), in the same way that importing a python file executes the **init**.py code that resides in the same directory.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible from `clr.AddReference`, as far as I know.

If your assembly has an IronPython module, you can run code when it is imported (a la `__init__.py`). An IronPython module is pretty simple to set up:

```
[assembly: PythonModule("mymodule", typeof(MyModule))]
public static class MyModule
{
    [SpecialName]
    public static void PerformModuleReload(PythonContext/*!*/ context, PythonDictionary/*!*/ dict) {
        // module initialization code
    }

    // variables, functions, classes, etc. that appear in the module
}
```

Don't get confused by the "Reload" part of the name; it's called when the module is loaded as well as every time it is reloaded.

If your assembly will be used outside of IronPython, you can put this module in a separate assembly that references your original module. If you want some examples of how to write modules, check out the source to the `IronPython.Modules` project on http://ironpython.codeplex.com.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible.

The only way is to change the `clr.AddReference` method. As IronPython is open source it should be easy.